# BAMT Edimax wireless adapter join wpa2 network

Tags: wpa2-psk, wpa-supplicant

I have managed to get my Edimax EW-7811Un wireless adapter registered and the correct driver installed, but need some help getting it connected to my WPA2 PSK network.

BAMT is based on debian and I've tried following some of the raspberry pi tutorials with no luck.

```
root@bamt-miner:/home/user# lsusb 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 7392:7811 Edimax Technology Co., Ltd EW-7811Un 802.11n Wi  reless Adapter [Realtek RTL8188CUS]

root@bamt-miner:/home/user# lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
8192cu                542854  0


wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 80:1f:02:7c:6e:3a
          inet6 addr: fe80::821f:2ff:fe7c:6e3a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:885 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2 errors:0 dropped:245 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:198810 (194.1 KiB)  TX bytes:23383 (22.8 KiB)

wlan0:avahi Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 80:1f:02:7c:6e:3a
          inet addr:169.254.5.114  Bcast:169.254.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

My /etc/network/interfaces looks like this

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
    wpa-ssid myawesomeinternethotspot
    wpa-psk myunbreakablewpa2password
iface default inet dhcp
```

Is there something that i'm missing?